# How to limit the objects in angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, pug, angularjs-limitto

My $scope values:
I am getting array values in `$scope.articles`

Example: `$scope.articles` values looks like:

```
[
   {
    date: 'some', 
    category: [ {name: "Sports"}, {name: "News"}, {name: "Cinema"} ] 
   }
]
```

My table view: (jade)

```
table
  tbody
   tr
     th Date
     th Categories

   tr(ng-repeat='article in articles')
     td
       span {{ article.date }}
     td
      span(ng-repeat='cat in article.category') 
       span {{ cat.name}}
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PW51BBnQEv589rIdnaCK?p=preview

This is working correctly, but if category array consists of more than 3 objects table become messy,
So I want to limit the category, I want to display only 2 objects

For Example in UI I want to show the category **Sports** and **News** in the table, then I want to put this .....  dot type UI, if user hover near the ... dot, I want to show other category For Example **Cinema**

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a custom filter which give you the 2 record of the array & pass a skip limit in filter so you can get next 2 objects of array when click or hover dots...

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for **[`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cat in article.category | limitTo: 2">
```

Comment: limitTo not working for objects. Read the full question bro

Comment: what do you mena by working for objects? anything with ng-repeat should with with limitTo

Comment: OH sorry its my mistake. now how to display other? for eg if use mouse hover near category, all category needs to be shown. see my question

Comment: you need to basically remove the filter limitTo, i would suggest you to use a custom filter and call the filter on the mouse move event

Comment: I basically write simple logic to remove limit its working, but the problem is if i hover all category of below also displayed, if i hover via first row i want to show only first row arrays

Comment: reproduce it using plunker